# Rails mountable engine and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, rails-engines

I have a mountable rails engine with Devise. When I copy my migrations and run rake db:migrate in the dummy app it works just fine.

But when I use a new rails app, add my engine to the gem file, copy migrations and run rake db:migrate I get this error `"uninitialized constant Devise".`

I have this in my routes file:

```
mount Cms::Engine, :at => '/', :as => 'cms'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: does your engines gemspec specify a dependency for Devise?

Comment: Hi Kyle, yes: s.add_development_dependency "devise"

Comment: when you `gem list` from within the project directory, is Devise listed? Also, if you have a development dependency, the gem is only included when you are in development mode. I would do `s.add_dependency` instead of `s.add_development_dependency`

Comment: devise is listed as: devise (2.1.2, 2.0.4) - Good idea.. it should be changed. Any idea what else it could be ? - If I include my gem + call engine in the routes file it should pick up devise, as it does in the dummy app (inside the engine)

Comment: I think the problem is that the gem dependencies are not being loaded. Is it sufficient to write: s.add_dependency "devise" in the gemspec ?

Comment: I ended up, just putting in devise as a gem in the app that I am developing..

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you. I have been at work. You can email me if you want a little more help but I'll be off and on tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to explicitly require devise in your engine's `engine.rb` file.

From the [Rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#other-gem-dependencies):

> Note that if you want to immediately require dependencies when the engine is required, you should require them before the engine's initialization. For example:

So just add `require 'devise'` to the top or your `engine.rb`.